# Chrome add display none for elements

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

On my site chrome adds `display:none` css to elements on load.

following is the css code added by chrome

```
:root .ad-row, :root #ad-footer, :root .ad-sidebar, :root .ad-content, :root #content > #right > .dose > .dosesingle, :root #content > #center > .dose > .dosesingle, :root .ad-header {
    display: none !important;
}
```

I removed all js files and checked but its not working.

Comment: Looks like it is because of some adblocker in action? Check the right side to find the source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not happening because of chrome but because of styles from some ad blocker extension which you might have installed on chrome.

It happened with me too. For one of my project, I was unable to see some div elements on firefox. The problem is that you are having the word "ad" in your class or id  name. Please don't do that. Because these ad blocker extension hides everything that have the keyword "ad" in them.

**How to solve the issue:**

Instead of trying to remove ad blockers from your browser, change your class and id name to something else. Because if the visitor of your website have any ad blocker installed then they might experience the same thing which you have.

And never use "ad" word in your class or id name.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have ad-block on your Chrome, correct? All the none displayed classes are from advertising boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it in incognito mode, probably some Google Chrome addon adds it's own styles.